# find a group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

We concider two groups:

1. $(P(X),\Delta)$ - group of power set of $X$ with operation defined as the symmetric difference, $|X|=n$.
2. the group of n-tuples $(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)$ (where $a_i= 1$ or $a_i=0$ for all $i$) with the operation $(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)\oplus(b_1,\ldots ,b_n)=(a_1\oplus b_1,\ldots ,a_n\oplus b_n)$

Both groups have the same order and my question is if there is such an isomorphism between them? If so, how to construct it?

Comment: You ought to split up these two very different questions into two different posts...

Answer (score 2):

The natural candidate for an isomorphism is $X \mapsto ([x_1 \in X], \dots, [x_n \in X])$ where $X = \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ and $[x_i \in X]=1$ or $0$ according to whether $x_i \in X$.

Comment: shouldn't it go from $P(X)$ instead of $X$? cause if it goes from X, then any $x_i$ belongs to $X$ and we get $(1,\ldots ,1)$.

Comment: @Yelon, the map is *taking* $X$ to some tuple, not *going from* $X$.

Comment: ooh, ok :D thanks!